# Поиск по определённому тексту в MySQL

Tags: search, база-данных, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages`");
```

Как найти в **messages** например: **test**?

Что-то вроде такого:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` strpos('test')");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` LIKE %test%");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `field_name` LIKE "some_text"
```

Чтобы искать по двум полям - добавляете условие.
Вместо `some_text` подставляете искомый текст. Со спец.символами(`%`, `_`), если пожелаете.
Например, `` ..`field_name` LIKE "%test%".. `` для поиска записей, где поле `field_name` содержит в себе слово "`test`".